# Randomize Keno Card

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub GetRandomCell()
    Range("A1:J10").Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
            Cell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
        End If
    Next

    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim RNG     As Range

    Set RNG = Range("A1:J10")

    Dim randomCell As Long

    i = 1        
    Do While i < 20
        randomCell = Int(Rnd * RNG.Cells.Count) + 1
        If RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color <> vbYellow Then
            RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

This is the code im using to create a randomized keno card. However, the last few times we've played (there is about 20 of us) a few of us have found we are playing the same card. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Voted to close this question.  "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. "

Comment: The Keno card is 1 to 100 with 10 rows.

Comment: I would think the desired behavior would be completely randomized. That seemed to be a given in the question.

Comment: Then it would appear to me that it was not re-run between printing the results.  Because every time I run it, it highlights a random 20 numbers.

Comment: I think the problem is clearly presented, and should not be closed.  Nineteen random numbers are selected.  The chance of those nineteen numbers being repeated within a small series of runs should be extremely low.  One thought - how random are excel random numbers?  List based, or some random input from the CPU?

Comment: However I need to clarify, that Do While i < 20 should be 21 and is a mistype. 20 random numbers.

Comment: In multiple (>20) runs with your code, I have been unable to replicate the duplicate card problem.  Are you sure your friends aren't just cheating?

Comment: I wouldn't put it past them. Could just be fantastic chance too that we ended with 3 of the same. in any case, I got lots of great advice here, ill make some improvements to the code and vote. Thanks for the great help everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Randomize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/randomize-statement) function to randomize the seed for the `Rnd` function. Call it in each iteration to insure that `Rnd` doesn't use the same seed and give you not so Random results:

```
Sub GetRandomCell()
    Range("A1:J10").Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
            Cell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
        End If
    Next

    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim RNG     As Range

    Set RNG = Range("A1:J10")

    Dim randomCell As Long

    i = 1
    Do While i < 20
        Randomize
        randomCell = Int(Rnd * RNG.Cells.Count) + 1
        If RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color <> vbYellow Then
            RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI: you could get rid of the first loop and just put `RNG.Interior.Color = vbWhite` before the Do loop

Comment: This may be an issue. I also found this macro seperate from the other. I wrote this program over a year ago so hard to remember what was for what?

Answer (score 0):

`RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color` does not report out as a string--it reports out as a number.  vbYellow is 65535 to Excel.

So-- you need to adjust your If statement to:

```
If RNG.Cells(randomCell).Interior.Color <> 65535 Then
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, there is no functional difference between the term vbYellow and the number 65535.  This solution will not fix the problem above, but I am leaving it because the information in the comments is interesting.

Comment: `vbYellow` is a built in constant. It's value is exactly equal to `65535` For fun you can `debug.print vbYellow` Your change doesn't change anything.

Comment: `VbYellow` is the same as then number.  Put `? vbYellow` in the immediate window and it returns 65535.

Comment: If the If/Then statement is working, how is it possible to select two of the same cards?

Comment: That is the crux of the matter isn't it?  But this change will not fix the issue.  It is the same `vbYellow = 65535`.  Try this in the immediate window `? vbYellow = 65535` it will return `TRUE` to vba they are the same thing.  It is like dates to vba `1/1/2018 = 43101`.  it is simple a text representation of a number.